# glassfish server If you access the IP address directly, you do not know how to redirect it to the domain

Tags: glassfish, payara

The application is running on the Payara server.

On the Grassfish server administrator screen, the domain is set to.

It can be accessed by the domain without any problem.

I have a question.

If you access the application from its IP address, you can connect without problems.

If you access the IP address directly, you do not know how to redirect it to the domain.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an type A record DNS record which points your domain to your server's ip address.

You can change the records usually in some kind of admin gui at the provider where you registered the domain.

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types#A

Comment: The setting of A record is completed. Do you know how to redirect to the domain when I access the IP address? Glassfish server.